# Scala inherit from class with static methods

Tags: scala, inheritance, polymorphism

I have an abstract class SQLTuple that I want to extend from:

```
abstract class SQLTuple() {
    val attributes : List[FieldName[_]]
}
```

For example, `Students` is a subclass of `SQLTuple`

```
class Student() extends SQLTuple {
    val id = Field[Int]("id")
    val name = Field[String]("name")
    val age = Field[Int]("age")

    override val attributes = List(id, name, age)
}
```

I also have another function that takes in a `SQLTuple` or subclass of `SQLTuple` and depending the class, I want to get its `attributes`.

```
def apply[A <% SQLTuple](table_name : String) = {
    val attributes = A.attributes
    new SQLSet[A](Relation(table_name, attributes))
}
```

I know this does not work because attributes is not a static field. If I wanted to make it one, I could create a companion object for the `SQLTuple` class. However, I cannot figure out how to enforce subclasses of `SQLTuple` to inherit any static methods defined in a companion object. It there any way to do this?

Comment: There is no such thing as `static` in Scala. Object is just singleton instance of particular class. You can't extend `object` and consequently it doesn't make sense to restrict parameter of the function to be subtype of `object`. Maybe if you describe what particular problem you're trying to solve with your code, we'll be able to help you find the alternative.

Comment: btw, why use views bounds (the `<%`)  any ways? Do they even work for type without type parameters?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this using implicits:

```
case class Attributes[A](value: List[FieldName[_]])

abstract class SQLTuple[A](implicit val attributes: Attributes[A])

class Student() extends SQLTuple[Student] 

object Student {
  val id = Field[Int]("id")
  val name = Field[String]("name")
  val age = Field[Int]("age")
  implicit val studentAttrs = Attributes[Student](List(id, name, age))
}

def apply[A <: SQLTuple[A]](table_name: String)(implicit attributes: Attributes[A]) = {
  val attributes = attributes.value
  new SQLSet[A](Relation(table_name, attributes))
}
```

Comment: Clever indeed. Here was used the fact that search for implicits includes companion object. So, whenever `apply[Student]` is called, `attributes` from corresponding `Student` object are injected. But I'd also like to note that parameterising `Attributes` and `SQLTuple` is unnecessary.  Also, instead of making `attributes` implicit it's possible to create separate implicit `def` in `SQLTuple` that returns `attributes` (original OP's declaration) wrapped in special `Attributes` type (only for implicit search). [Here is my version](https://gist.github.com/Aivean/f5f80119305799aedf7c6ec8736c52c9).

Comment: Interesting. But it relies on `object Student extends Student`, which may be wrong, depending on the intended usage.

Comment: In that particular case my approach is not different from yours. Yours too requires class `Student` and companion object `Student` with implicit attributes. I just decided to declare it differently, but it doesn't really matter.

Comment: What I meant is that with a setup like this I'd normally expect an instance of class `Student` to correspond to a row in the database, so that there is are methods like `allStudents: Something[Student]`, you can get the `name` of a specific `Student`, etc. They aren't shown in the question, but this could be a simplification. In this case the companion object shouldn't extend `Student` because it doesn't represent a row.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comment Scala doesn't have static values. But by looking at your example you don't even seem to want static values. In

```
abstract class SQLTuple() {
    val attributes : List[FieldName[_]]
}
```

The `val attributes` is a *abstract val*. And as such it will need to be defined for every direct subclass of `SQLTuple`. The simplest solution would be something like:

```
def apply[A <: SQLTuple](table_name : String, sql_tuple: A) = {
    val attributes = sql_tuple.attributes
    new SQLSet[A](Relation(table_name, attributes))
}
```

Comment: This is actually the solution I am currently implementing. I am writing a DSL however and I was hoping to find a syntax that was less redundant. It seems silly to have to call the function with both `A` and an instance of `A` if `attributes` has the same value for any arbitrary instance of `A`. I just am not sure if this is possible in Scala.